# How do I create a table with multiple elements(columns) in a row in React.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have an array of json objects and I want to populate these elements in a table. Currently, I want to hold 2 elements per row, but I would like the code to be expandable, as my data size can grow over time and I can hold multiple elements per row.

I am aware of the map function that can populate same elements repeatedly. I have a hack at this point to pass two elements as props into a row element, and just populate the row repeatedly. I am looking for a better solution, so I can expand my code to be able to hold multiple elements(columns) in one row for the table.

Edited:
My current hack

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ExperienceRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let workItemOne = this.props.workItemOne;
    let workItemTwo = this.props.workItemTwo;
    
    if(workItemTwo === null)
    {
       return (
          <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
              {workItemOne.summary}
            </Col>
          </Row>
       );
    }
    else {
      return (
          <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
              {workItemOne.summary}
            </Col>
            <Col md={6}>
              {workItemTwo.summary}
            </Col>
          </Row>
      );
    }
  }
};

export default class Experience extends React.Component {

  populateExperienceRows(data) {
    console.log("get that exp");
    console.log(this.props);

    let length = data.length;
    let rows = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
      if( i === length - 1)
      {
        console.log("two elements");
        rows.push(<ExperienceRow workItemOne={data[i]} workItemTwo={null}/>);
      }
      else {
        console.log("one element");
        rows.push(<ExperienceRow workItemOne={data[i]} workItemTwo={data[i+1]}/>);
      }
    }
    
    console.log(rows);
    return rows;
  };

  render() {
    /*
    let data = [{"summary":"helloworld"},
                {"summary":"what is this" },
                {"summary":"Something something" }
               ];
               */
    let getExpRows = this.populateExperienceRows(this.props.experienceData);
    return (
      <div>
      <Grid>
        <h2>Experience</h2>
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
        {getExpRows}
      </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }

};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? A snippet of code to show that you have something on your end will be helpful.

Comment: I just added my source code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sm=6` for that .. check [this documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#grids-clearfix) .

```
import {Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';


render() {
    return (
     <Grid>
      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col sm={6} md={6}>I am first column</Col>
        <Col sm={6} md={6}>I am 2nd column</Col>

      </Row>
     </Grid>
    )
}
```

### DEMO :

1. [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/kd7Lwgy3/11/)
2. [Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/kd7Lwgy3/11/show/)

### DEMO with long content :

1. [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/kd7Lwgy3/13/)
2. [Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/kd7Lwgy3/13/show/)

Comment: I know how to add two elements in a row. What if I have a lot of json elements, and I want to populate multiple rows with two elements per row.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same situation and saw this question unanswered.

My understanding of the question is you want to add rows that contains 2 columns for each row. As the list grows, your components will grows the rows and add columns accordingly.

This is how I solved mine.
First create an array of components to render.
Then create a nested array.

Only after that, map over the nested array and add row components.

```
changeCells(numbers){

    var cells =  keys.map((i)=>{return (
            <Col />
    )});    

    var nestedArrayCell=[];

    for (var i=0; i< cells.length;i=i+2){
        nestedArrayCell.push(cells.slice(i, i+1)); 
    }
    return nestedArrayCell;
}

render(){
        return (
        <div>
            {this.cells.map((groupCells)=>(<Row>{groupCells}</Row>))}
        </div>
        );
    }
```